# Constructor function idea :D

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, minify

I don't know is it possible or worst idea ever lol; 
however i'm trying to write constructor for my model class which uses String array and automatically bind parameters from it :)
Thank you for wasting your gold time on my poor question :D
here is example:
edited: code and my point is, i create object of this class just giving String[] to constructor .... :(

```
//Like ---->>>>
public class MemberEducation{
String name;
String surname;
String address;
//empty constructor
public MemberEducation(){
}
//it's for parameters
public MemberEducation(String[] a){
int i=0;       
for(String val:a){
my_parameters[i]=a;// my parameters mean surname, name, and address
i++; 
}
}
// it's my solution now i'm using, create new object with empty constructor         
then set  all parameter with String array
public  void setAll(String[] a){
this.surname=a[0];
this.name=a[1];
this.address=a[2];
}
```

Comment: What is the question?..

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You were assigning `String Array` where it is expecting a `String`,Thats where it went wrong.I think you are looking for this

### Solution

```
public class MemberEducation{
    String[] arr = new String[10];// just taking size 10 for test

    public MemberEducation(String[] a) {
            int i = 0;
            for (String val : a) {
                arr[i++] = val;// arr is an string array
            }
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MemberEducation(args);
    }
}
```